# AlertDialog Title and Message set to center

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have my alert dialog and:

- I wanted to set the title and the message at the center.
- MESSAGE: I want to place --- (1) SCORE -- and below the word score is the (2) score itself.
- Can I make the SCORE a bit bigger than the score itself?

Answer (score 1):

By default you can not customise the contents of the message when you call "setMessage()". However you can pass in a custom view. Have a look at:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Specifically:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setView(android.view.View)

This way you can make a view with the Fonts and Positions of the text you want on the Alert.

Hope this helps!